# How to Assign ArrayList hashmap<String,Double[]> to List

Tags: java

I'm trying to assign Hashmap values of Double[] to List, but it is throwing an error:

> "The method add(Double) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments 
>        (Double[])"

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>>) pd.getArrayList();

List<Double> empid = new ArrayList<Double>();
Iterator itr = arl.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    HashMap<String, Double[]> map = (HashMap<String, Double[]>) itr.next();
    empid.add(map.get("id")));
}
```

How can I cast `Double[]` to `Double.Request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you seem to be looking is this line:

```
empid.add(map.get("id")));
```

changed to this:

```
empid.addAll(Arrays.asList(map.get("id"))));
```

It will convert an array of `Double` to a `List` of `Double`, and `addAll` will add all items from the resulting collection to your target collection `empid`.

Comment: Hi Thanks this one also works,but my main problem is still not resolved.I will post it as new question.

Answer (score 1):

If converting to `List<Double>` is your only option, try this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>>) pd.getArrayList();

List<Double> empid = new ArrayList<Double>();
Iterator itr = arl.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    HashMap<String, Double[]> map = (HashMap<String, Double[]>) itr.next();
    for (Double d : map.get("id") {
        empid.add(d);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks This works,but it deos not seems to solve my problem at later stage.But still Thanks for solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a bigger issue than casting. You have an array of `Doubles`, and you ultimately want a single `Double`.

That's not a casting problem, but a problem of how you manipulate those `Doubles` to give you one only.

Perhaps what you're really wanting is to iterate through that array, and add each `Double` in turn to the list. But this is really a requirements issue.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Yes, you are right , I am trying to do that , because I am using this list data to build chart data using achartengine in android , the inbuilt library accepts List type .So I am facing problem converting this data to List.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provide, you must change

```
List<Double> empid = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

by

```
List<Double[]> empid = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
```

to make it compiles. But I guess this is not what you are trying to achieve. It that what you want to do ? :

```
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>>) pd.getArrayList();
        List<Double> empid = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Iterator itr = arl.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            HashMap<String, Double[]> map = (HashMap<String, Double[]>) itr.next();
            empid.addAll(Arrays.asList(map.get("id")));
        }
```

Comment: Hi Yanflea

Thanks for timely response, Yes I did that intially,
but it is creating an array for each entry of the value exisiting,I don't want  that to happen because the inbuilt library accespts List type in achartengine for android charts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `map.get("id")` will return `Double[]` but `empid` is of type `Double`.

You just change

```
List<Double> empid = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

to

```
List<Double[]> empid = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
```

Comment: Hi Adarsh, If I do that it is creating an array for each entry, how do I add all the entries in Arraylist into Single arrayList, without creating separate arrays for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert an array of type Double in a list where the elements are "single" Doubles.

To insert an array in the empid list you should declare it in this way:

```
List<Double[]> empid = new ArrayList<Double[]>();
```

Then when you call add on this list you can pass an argument of type Double[].

Comment: if I  use above , I want to add the all values of Hash into single array ,where as for each value it is creating an array rather I want to add all values into single array, how do I achieve that.