# ArrayList<Hashmap<String,Double[]> assigning the values to a single Double[]

Tags: java

I am able to assign the Hash-map values to List double[] using following code, but for each entry in the Hash-map, it is creating separate array.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>> arl =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Double[]>>)pd.getArrayList();

 while (itr.hasNext()) {
     HashMap< String,Double[]> map = (HashMap<String,Double[]>) itr.next();
     empid.add((Double[])map.get("id"));
 }
```

How do I get all the entries into single array of double[].

Comment: Don't type your signature in the question. Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: There's nothing "being created" here at all--it's a list of maps with `Double[]` values, and you're putting those `Double[]` values into an array. What do you *want*? If this is related to your other two questions about this, why are you using a `Double[]` in the first place if you want a single `Double`?

Comment: Also, don't assume the context of your question. For instance, someone who hasn't seen your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993463/how-to-assign-arraylist-hashmapstring-double-to-list) would never understand what `empid` means.

Comment: So you don't want a List<Double[]>, you just want a single 'double[]'?

Comment: Yes Greg , I am looking to get all entries into single array.

Comment: You should really be declaring `arl` as `List<Map<String, Double[]>>` (using interfaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making the same mistake again. You need to add Double to list, not arrays of Double. So similarly to what I said in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993463/how-to-assign-arraylist-hashmapstring-double-to-list?lq=1), change your code like this:

```
empid.addAll(Arrays.asList(map.get("id"))));
```

To get array from the list after the list is fully built with values from your map:

```
Double[] arrayOfDoubles = empid.toArray(new Double[]{});
```

Comment: Thanks maskimov, you provide elegant and simple solutions for a beginner like me in java.Thanks Once again